# EF Core Navigation Property Cycle

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Consider the following

**Models:**

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // more fields...

    // Navigation Property
    public IList<Post> Posts {get; set;}
}

public class Posts
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public Guid BlogID {get; set;}
    public string Author {get; set;}
    // more fields...

    // Navigation Property
    public Blog Blog {get; set;}
}
```

In **DbContext.OnModelCreating**:

```
// Primary Keys
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasKey(c => c.ID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasKey(c => c.ID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Posts)
            .WithOne(c => c.Blog)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.BlogID)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.ID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .WithOne(c => c.Blog)
            .HasMany(c => c.Posts)     
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.BlogID)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.ID);
```

This all works, the problem is then I fetch a **Blog** it contains a **Post** which contains the **Blog** which contains a list of **Posts** which each contain the **Blog**
and so on.

[image]

**How can I limit this to a specific level of nesting ?**
I checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and could not find a solution.

Comment: why that is an issue? What EF does it is doing LazyLoading, so when you are clicking or getting next property it travels to the Database and get it for you.

Comment: There is no lazy loading yet. But the navigation properties are just linked together. So `blog,Posts[0].Blog == blog`. This is not nesting, the properties point to one and the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can limit that at all. But also I don't think that can cause any issues.

EntityFramework is dealing with `navigation properties` by replacing (overriding) their functionality with actual query to the database. This approach is called `LazyLoading`.

That means, everytime you access the property, it just do a call to the database and brings the data for you, and it can do this forever, as you requesting it to.

I hope that explains it?

Further explanation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Regards

Comment: Is there a way to create the relation using the fluent api without navigation properties ?

Comment: first of all why do you think that is a problem? I don't think you can do replationship without the navigation properties. You can turn that to EagerLoading instead of LazyLoading, then it will have the data you Include and nothing more.

Comment: the problem occurs when mapping the Database-Model to the Api-Model. (Stackoverflow Exception). I could simply set the navigation property to null, but thought the might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: yeah, that is not an option I agree. What are you using to do mapping?

Comment: I use AutoMapper. It's only a problem when creating/updating. When I manually fetch it from the db, I can specify what should be included using **.Include**.

Comment: I am fairly sure you can set that in Automapper. Cant remeber from top of my head though.

Comment: This is incorrect answer. There is no lazy loading. Navigation properties are not made virtual in question. Regardless of which way you populate navigations, EF does fix up so both sides of navigation will be pointing to each other. This is typical serialization issue which you need to deal with.